# Unit test in magento 2 Error: Call to a member function getAllVisibleItems() on null

Tags: magento2, unit-tests, phpunit, magento2.2.3

Am finding difficult to unit test my custom functions. Below is my custom module's model function which i used for fetching cart informations.

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\MiniCart\Model;

use Namespace\MiniCart\Api\CartInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote;

class Cartupdate implements CartInterface
{

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
 */
protected $_customerSession;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface
 */
protected $quoteRepository;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart
 */
protected $_cart;
protected $_product;
protected $_formkey;
protected $_storemanager;

public function __construct(
     \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
     \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,
     \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
     \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
     \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formkey,
     \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storemanager,
     \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
)
{
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->_quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    $this->_cart = $cart;
    $this->_product = $product;
    $this->_formkey = $formkey;
    $this->_storemanager = $storemanager;
    $this->priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
}

public function object() {

    $itemsVisible = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
    $items        = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
    $subtotal     = $this->priceCurrency->format($this->_cart->getQuote()->getSubtotal(), true, 0);
    $totalItems   = round($this->_cart->getQuote()->getItemsQty());
    $cart_details = array();
    $cartList     = array();
    foreach($itemsVisible as $item) {
        $proid     = $item->getProductId();
        $item_id   = $item->getItemId();
        $item_sku  = $item->getSku();
        $item_name = $item->getName();
        $item_qty  = $item->getQty();
        $item_rate = $item->getPrice() * $item_qty;
        $item_price= $item_price= $this->priceCurrency->format($item_rate, true, 0);
        $image_url = $this->getProductImageUrl($proid);
        $url_key   = $this->_storemanager->getStore()->getBaseUrl() . $this->getProductCollection($proid)->getUrlKey() . ".html";
        $cart_details[$proid] = array
              (
              "pro_id"     => $proid,
              "item_id"    => $item_id,
              "item_sku"   => $item_sku,
              "item_name"  => $item_name,
              "item_qty"   => $item_qty,
              "item_price" => $item_price,
              "imageUrl"   => $image_url,
              "url_key"    => $url_key
              );
    }
    $cartList['products']   = $cart_details;
    $cartList['subtotal']   = $subtotal;
    $cartList['totalItems'] = $totalItems;

    return json_encode($cartList);

}
}
```

And my Unit test function is

```
<?php


namespace Namespace\MiniCart\Test\Unit\Model;

use Magento\Framework\TestFramework\Unit\Helper\ObjectManager;

class MinicartObjectTest extends  \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase {


protected $_desiredResult;
protected $_actulResult;


/**
 * unset the variables and objects after use
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function tearDown() {

}

/**
 * used to set the values to variables or objects.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function setUp() {

    $this->customerSessionMock = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Customer\Model\Session::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $this->cartRepositoryInterface = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $this->cart = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $this->product = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $this->formKey = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $this->storeManagerInterface = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $this->priceCurrencyInterface = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $this->sourceModel = new \Namespace\MiniCart\Model\Cartupdate(
            $this->customerSessionMock,
            $this->cartRepositoryInterface,
            $this->cart,
            $this->product,
            $this->formKey,
            $this->storeManagerInterface,
            $this->priceCurrencyInterface
        );
}


public function testCartObject() {

    $this->_actulResult = $this->sourceModel->object();
    $this->_desiredResult = "";
    $this->assertEquals($this->_desiredResult, $this->_actulResult);

}

}
```

It throws me

> Error: Call to a member function getAllVisibleItems() on null

And also help me how can i assert my test function.

Comment: Got any solution?

Comment: No, not still..

Comment: @Technocracker & Prabhu, got any solution?